# GoogleTV: Change the navigation using the keyboard Dpad between two Fragmentlists

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-tv

I am making an application for android. I have a Activity and in it two fragmentList. When moving the DPAD left or right, I want to control what position you are positioned in the Fragmentlist below. For example, want to go to position 4 of the first fragmentlist at position 8 of the siguiende press Right on the DPAD.

Try to explain better:

I am making an application for GoogleTV, so keyboard handling is very important. I has two fragmentlist with items. OnItemSelectedListener I'm using so that when a item has the focus, also is pressed. When the fragmentlist1 changes position, the fragmentList2 change.   When I'm at the Item 3 in FragmentList2, then I left key pulse. I want to return to item 1 of fragmentLis1. The default is the item 3 for fragmentList1.

Added the code of fragment 1.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    listView.setSelection(position);
    changeItem(position);   
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    listView.setSelection(position);
    changeItem(position);   
}

public void changeItem(int position){

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();       
    Fragment1 f1 = new Fragment1();
    Fragment2 f2 = new Fragment2();

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        transaction.replace(R.id.second_fragment, f1);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
        break;
    case 1:
        transaction.replace(R.id.second_fragment, f2);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }       
}
```

would something like nextfocusleft between Fragmentlists?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the inituitive behaviour is the jump from third item on left list to third item on right list on dpad right. Thats why I mentioned in your earlier post to explain the usecase.

Answer (score 0):

In the Activity, I'd create a member variable for the position in FragmentList1, and wrap it with a getter function that can handle any defaults or special business logic.

Then, I'd create an onKeyUp listener, and if I detect a LEFT from FragmentList2, intercept it and modify as needed.